# How to open monitor case? (LG Flatron L196WTQ)

Tags: display, lcd, repair

My monitor (LG Flatron L196WTQ) has broken recently and I know the problem is with the inverter.  From what I have read online, replacing the capacitors on the inverter board might fix it.  The problem is that I can't open the monitor.  I took off all the screws but still cannot get at the insides.  Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the post below which was quite helpful.  I just had to give it some more force with a flathead screwdriver.  I will be repairing the caps tomorrow.

http://www.ccl-la.com/blog/index.php/lg-l196wtq-bf-lcd-monitor-repair/

Answer (score 1):

I found a service manual, which describes how to disassemble the monitor: http://www.fixdevice.com/smanuals/file/39118.html

And yes you are probably right about the caps, they are most likely dead if they are electrolytic capacitors.